# Finding Group name by using GeneratedUID

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

In Mac OS X Lion, given a group's GeneratedUID, what command can I do a reverse lookup and find the group name?  DSeditgroup (group name) will give me the GUID, but I'm looking for the reverse.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, so this is probably more for future reference:

```
root# dscl localhost search  /Search/Groups GeneratedUID ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000050
admin           GeneratedUID = (
    "ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000050"
)
```

While this was run on 1.11 I think this holds true for all osx>10.4 or so, the transition being when NetInfo was ousted.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for answering. This worked well

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the getgrnam() or getgrgid() C functions included in Mac OS X.

See the  getgrent manual page.

```
man getgrent
```

Also here is an example that needs some work, but something along these lines should allow given a GID number, lookup and print the group name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main()
{
    struct group myGroup;

    struct group *grp;

    grp = &myGroup;

    grp = getgrgid(20); // <--- Enter your group ID number

    if (grp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong\n");
    }

    printf("Group Name is: %s\n", myGroup.gr_name);
}
```